# AngularJS Resource Constructor with Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a resource in AngularJS, for example

```
var Posts = $resource('posts/:postId', { postId: '@_id' })
```

I can query a list (array) of all posts with

```
$scope.posts = Posts.query();
```

I can create a single post in the constructor

```
$scope.post = new Posts({
    title: ...,
    content: ...
});
```

But what I like to but cant do is: create a list of posts with that constructor, like:

```
$scope.posts = new Posts([
    {
        title: ...,
        content: ...
    },
    {
        title: ...,
        content: ...
    },
    {
        title: ...,
        content: ...
    },
]);
```

With this I can only do `$scope.posts.save()` which tries to push the whole list to a single post and leads to an error. Isn't it possible to `$scope.posts[...].save()`/`$scope.posts[...].remove()` them individually?

Answer (score 1):

I did the obvious:

```
$scope.posts = [];
[
    {
        title: ...,
        content: ...
    },
    {
        title: ...,
        content: ...
    },
    {
        title: ...,
        content: ...
    },
].foreEach(function(post) {
    $scope.posts.push(new Posts(post));
});
```

It does exactly what I want.